# The method x isn't defined for the type 'Type'. [Abstract classes and factory constructors]

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, abstract-class, factory

First of all, I read as much as posts about that a lot, but I am still confused. I am trying to create generic classes for json serializing.

The same json is coming for all 'GetAll' apis except their 'data' field changes only.

This is my generic class for the 'data' field.

```
abstract class GenericDataModel {
  factory GenericDataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonAsMap) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

There is no error about that class.

And then this is my generic class for the jsons itself:

```
class GenericGetAllModel<T extends GenericDataModel> {
  int? pageNumber;
  int? pageSize;
  ..
  ...
  ....
  String? message;
  String? errors;
  List<T?>? data;

  GenericGetAllModel({
    this.pageNumber,
    ..
    ...
    ....
    this.message,
    this.errors,
    this.data,
  });

  factory GenericGetAllModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonAsMap) =>
      GenericGetAllModel(
        data: T.fromJson(jsonAsMap),
        pageNumber: jsonAsMap['pageNumber'] as int?,
        pageSize: jsonAsMap['pageSize'] as int?,
        ..
        ...
        ....
        message: jsonAsMap['message'] as String?,
        errors: jsonAsMap['errors'] as String?,
      );
}
```

The line `data: T.fromJson(jsonAsMap),` throws: `The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.`.

I have tried to change `GenericDataModel` to this:

```
abstract class GenericDataModel {
  GenericDataModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonAsMap) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

And this:

```
abstract class GenericDataModel {
 static GenericDataModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonAsMap) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

It still doesn't work.

By the way

```
..
...
....
```

means there are a lot of fields there.

Comment: All of the other posts you saw should have explained that `T.fromJson` simply isn't possible.  `static` methods and constructors are not considered part of the interface.  You instead would need to pass a `T Function(Map<String, dynamic>)` callback.  Or really, don't serialize/deserialize JSON yourself and use an existing code-generation solution, such as [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value).

Comment: Thank you, I will continue with json_serializable package